# Android:id throws me error inside a DrawerLayout content View

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to place a textview in main activity with left drawer. Textview can be placed with no problem, but when i'am adding Android:id in Textview, then it throws me Error:

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.

This Code: Works

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:openDrawer="start">

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But this code doesn't

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:openDrawer="start">

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I just have add one line of code

```
android:id="@+id/textView1"
```

Comment: Anyone please??

Comment: Can you please show the entire error?

Comment: Typically, you use a FrameLayout and a Fragment for something less simple. https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#DrawerLayout

Comment: Every time i add a new element in xml, i need to delete library and re install it... Is this any library bug? The error is edited in my question

Comment: Delete which library? Delete how?

Comment: I delete App.Compat.V7 and Support.Designer from nugets and re install them. Then it doesn't throw error, till next element which i will add in xml

Comment: I'm not sure that actually "removes" them from your machine, only the project. But I don't use Xamarin, so can't really help there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem will likely occur when the version of your appcompat library and design support library doesn't match.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' // appcompat library
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'       //design support library
```